# Use an URL as a name to save a file

Tags: ios, swift

I download a json file with this code

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: NSURL(string: url)! as URL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let this = weakSelf{
```

and then I try to save it locally

```
let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).appendingPathComponent(url)
                        print(fileURL)
                        try data?.write(to: fileURL)
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
```

I want to use the url of the JSON file as its name when I try to save it. But I get an error tellig me that the path dose not exist... Every think works file it I try to save it with a normal name. Do you have an idea on how to solve that?

Comment: When print(fileURL) executes , what does it print?

Answer (score 1):

It’s a bad idea to use the url as a file name. You would probably want to process the url first, like remove scheme and slashes

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use an entire URL as file name because the URL (string) contains slashes and slashes are path separators in the file system.

You can use

```
url.lastPathComponent
```

to get the file name of the URL. And don't use `NSURL` in Swift 3. There is a native `URL` struct.